# Hit the back button but not kill the activity and let it be in Back Stack (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-view

I have 3 activities A, B and C.

I inflate activity B dynamically on a button click and the user can add as many views as he likes.

The operation is like this:

User sees "Activity A" first enters his details and clicks the save button and I take him to "Activity B" where he adds certain fields as many times he likes and when he clicks save again I take him to "Activity C".

Now when I am at A and go to B and add some views and enter text in TextViews and then hit save and go to C. From C if I hit back I see B intact along with all the inflated views and entered text obviously because it is saved in the Back Stack, but if I go from B to A by hitting back and then come back to B all the views are gone because it is removed from the Back Stack.

I wanted to know if it is possible to hold only one instance of B in the BackStack and not kill it at all when the user hits back? 
I had overriden back key but to no avail because the activity is killed anyways, some people suggested that I should save the entire views and data from it to a Parcelable ArrayList and regenerate them again in onCreate but that doesnt look feasible to me as I think we can save it in BackStack anyway.

I came across this guide at android developers http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html which says about these activity attributes

```
android:taskAffinity
android:launchMode
android:allowTaskReparenting
android:clearTaskOnLaunch
android:alwaysRetainTaskState
android:finishOnTaskLaunch
android:singleTask
android:singleInstance
```

But I am unaware of how to put them to use.

Has anyone tried this out yet? If so please help me put the pieces together.

Comment: You can't guarantee that any component of your app will exist for any given amount of time. That includes activities and services. If the device your app is running on is running low on resources, the Android OS will kill anything and everything  that it thinks isn't currently in use. If you accept user data then you MUST take steps to persist it in some way and not rely on the fact that it may or may not exist on the stack when you choose to go back or to recreate. From your question "...but that doesnt look feasible to me..." - I suggest you rethink as it's the only guaranteed way.

Comment: you have overridden the back button and it still goes back?  are you calling the super() method or something?

Comment: @MikeIsrael: Ive tried it without super but it still kills the activity, even if it is not killed then how will you prevent the start a new instance of activity B? It is always started as a new activity isnt it?

Comment: @mirroredAbstraction oh yeah didn't totally understand the issue there.  The best solution I could think of would require reworking your code.  I implement something similar to what you want to do, but by having one activity for all the states and switching out the views when needed.  I don't think that is really what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,I agree with Nandeesh.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                //bring back the previous activity do your logic here           
                return false; //means you don't want to remove the activity from stack 
            }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);  // means u want to remove the last activity from Activity stack.
    }

    so question  is that how u can go to other activity without remove it from stack, 
    you can use  :
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, JumptoActivity.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);*

example: at the switch case u can use this

if(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, NextActivity.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
                return false;
}
else
    return true;       //if you not write this then your  menu and other think will be affected.
```

Thank you I think this little bit information will be helpful for u.

Comment: Thank you but how should I make sure that android doesn't create a new instance of Activity B, I want to use the activity which is already in the stack.

Comment: use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT for the intent while launching

Comment: in the manifest file for Activity B set

android:noHistory="true"                                                so it will not create new instance and take it from history

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> @Override
> public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
>
>         switch(keyCode)
>         {
>         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
>             //bring back the previous activity do your logic here           
>             return false;
>         }
>     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
> }
> ```

You could use this, return false when activity should not be closed. use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to launch the previous activity