# Android - Relaunching an activity without having to re-create it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, task

I have an activity which shows an image (ViewCollection.java). I want to only create it once, then re-use that instance to further show more images from different calls (The activity is expensive to initialize).
So far, I launched the activity like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewCollection.java);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

And all activity calls from the ViewCollection activity are also called by the same method.
But despite this, the activity keeps getting destroyed when I start other activities from it...
What can I do to fix this?

*PS: The activity is set to "standard" launch mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the activity launchmode to singletop or set the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` .
Handle the intent in onNewIntent()
You can get further [details here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Edit: Though if back key is pressed on the activity or configuration changed since last time you entered the app, the activity will still be recreated

Comment: I overloaded the onBackPressed() function on the ViewCollection activity to call a new intent to the previous activity.
I want to be able to use the back button without finishing the activity, so that it is still there the next time I want to use it.

Comment: you will have to override onkeydown and return true if back key is encountered you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777164/hit-the-back-button-but-not-kill-the-activity-and-let-it-be-in-back-stack-andro

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of this line

```
 i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

that way you can go back to the previous activity