# Android Back Stack - UP button method

Tags: android

I have `Activity A` (Main) and `Activity B`.

Fact: Activity A has: `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Usual scenario is:

1. User launches application > `Activity A`.
2. User clicks an item > `Activity B`

   3.A. If user clicks on back/up buttons > Back to `A` (**without calling finish() on B**)

   - User clicks the SAME item as before > Forth to `B`.
   - At this point he can go back and forth without new instances. It's all in the stack and it doesn't recreate activities. (All right!)

   [image]

   3.B. If user clicks Home, then goes to task manager and brings the app to front > `Activity B` (all good, so far)

   - If user clicks UP button, it goes to TASK MANAGER, and I want it to go to `Activity A` (back button is expected to work this way, so let's focus on UP button).

Here's the implementation I have in `Activity B` for BACK and UP buttons.

```
@Override   
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    // I don't want to finish() the activity, so the user can reclick the same
    // item without reloading the whole activity again (webview slow when parsing html).
    return;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            // I don't want to finish() the activity... idem.
            // I need to implement here the bring Activity A to front
        break;
    }
}
```

So, what I want is: **to "Go Back" to `Activity A` keeping the same idea of using the stack to reload Activity B if needed, without using Intents (unless it calls activity to front, without adding items to the stack.)**

Let me know if I explained myself clearly and if you need more info.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've found this at: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

This is how I adapted it.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, Activity_A.class);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent).startActivities();
            } else {
                moveTaskToBack(true); // I want it this way. Don't worry.
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

But the method NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask is ALWAYS returning false.

I did the http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent part, so that's not the issue.

My problem is that I want to recognize if `Activity A` exists in the stack, for when i.e. the app is launched from the task manager.

How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: why not use action bar http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. Also check this link http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Yes, but I loose the "go forth" functionality that I want to keep, cause this finishes `Activity B`.

Comment: i din't get you "go forth" meaning?

Comment: From Activity B I can go back to Activity A, and it uses the stack.
If I click the same "item" of the list, it will go forth to Activity B within the stack as well, so no new contents are loaded (in this case to a webview). With the UP button, I loose this behavior.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Activities.  Once you navigate backwards in the stack, the activity you were just in is gone.  The only methods the API seems to offer is re-ordering the stack, but I haven't seen anything that allows for activity retention.  Its probably easier to have something like two Fragments side by side (if your screen is large enough), a Viewpager with two Fragments  (if your screen can't fit it all), or use the other commenter's suggestion of ActionBar, but keep everything within one activity.

Comment: Also, a quick google search turned up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777164/hit-the-back-button-but-not-kill-the-activity-and-let-it-be-in-back-stack-andro?rq=1

Comment: @Android Noob: Is not a bad idea, but I have already the whole app working, and I don't want to move big chunks of code at this stage.

Comment: how can I know if Activity A is still alive (in the stack), for me to use moveTaskToBack(true), or an Intent?

Answer (score 1):

moveTaskToBack moves the entire task to the background. it doesn't finish the activity.

in order to have full control of activities, you have some possible solutions:

1. create your own global manager for the activities, monitor each of them through all of their lifecycle and decide what to do on each event.
2. you could also finish each activity as soon as you go from it, and put "it" (just its name or something) in a stack and restore its state when you come back to it.
3. use fragments instead, and manage them all on a single activity. be warned of configurations changes though.

Comment: These seem to be good approaches, but unfortunately I can't start over. I'm using moveTaskToBack because I DON'T want to finish Activity B (just in case the user clicks the same item immediately).
What would be the best way to check if Activity A is still alive (not finished by the OS)?

Comment: what the user expects when he clicks on back is that the current screen will go, and you will show him the previous screen. there are some exceptions for this rule, but it's the normal approach. finishing activities is also a good thing as each of them use memory, and you don't want android to close your app because of OOM, just because the user switched between activities. you better save only the minimal things you need and restore them when the user re-opens the activity . for example, you could save&resotre listView state using onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState